# Passing information to another state with ui-router and $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I've got a gist here : https://gist.github.com/RobinDesir/e6e1d8780f84f4be27b7

What i'm trying to do is to go to a device page using ui-router (see the app.js). However, the redirection never work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: please create a plunker/jsfiddle and provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular router uses [`ui-sref`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) to navigate between states.

```
ui-sref="bleDetail({deviceId: device.id})"
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use this notation but it's not recommended to do so:

```
href="#/bleDetail/{{device.id}}"
```

Comment: I get an error while using this syntax :

*Error: Could not resolve 'bleDetail01:80:E1:00:00:AA' from state 'app.ble'*

Comment: Umm sorry, just edited my post, that one should work!